# Как по координатам определить город в Андроид?

Tags: android, координаты

Здравствуйте!
Есть 2 кода. Первый определяет координаты. Второй по вписанным вручную координатам определяет адреса. Как объединить эти 2 кода, чтобы получить приложение, в котором по координатам первого кода, можно было получить название города из второго кода? Главная проблема похоже в том, что в первом коде координаты типа String, а во втором координаты типа Double. Пробовал String перевести в Double. Не получается.

Вот первый код:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private LocationListener mLocationListener;
    private Location mLocation;
    private TextView mLatitudeTextView, mLongitudeTextView;

    private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // в метрах
    private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 2000; // в мс



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mLatitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLatitude);
        mLongitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLongitude);

        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        String provider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        mLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        mLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();

        showCurrentLocation(mLocation);

        // Регистрируемся для обновлений
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider,
                MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, MINIMUM_DISTANCE_FOR_UPDATES,
                mLocationListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        showCurrentLocation(mLocation);
    }

    protected void showCurrentLocation(Location location) {
        if (location == null) {
            mLatitudeTextView.setText("Не работает");
            mLongitudeTextView.setText("Не работает");
        }
        if (location != null) {
            mLatitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
        }

    }
```

А вот второй:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    double lat = 57.9989369;
    double lng = 56.2853801;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView myLatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
        TextView myLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);
        TextView myAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);

        myLatitude.setText("Широта: " + String.valueOf(lat));
        myLongitude.setText("Долгота: " + String.valueOf(lng));


        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);

            if (addresses != null) {
                Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder(
                        "Адрес:\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                    strReturnedAddress
                            .append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append(
                            "\n");
                }
                myAddress.setText(strReturnedAddress.toString());
            } else {
                myAddress.setText("Нет адресов!");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            myAddress.setText("Не могу получить адрес!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

форматируйте правильно свой код.
В первом фрагменте кода местоположение, после его определения возвращается объектом `Location`, у которого есть методы `location.getLatitude()` и `location.getLongitude()`. Они оба возвращают `double`. Используйте их значения во втором фрагменте.

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось