# Как получить местоположение юзера?

Tags: java, android

Для статистики нужно собирать данные о местоположении юзера (Страна и город) в котором было скачено и запущено приложение.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как по координатам определить город в Андроид?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419302/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b4)

Comment: При скачивании приложения вы никак не сможете получить страну и город конкретного пользователя потому, что вы не сможете выполнить никакой код при скачивании приложения. При первом запуске, например, сможете.

Comment: @metalurgus Так я про запуск и говорю. Что посоветуете?

Comment: `в котором было скачено приложение.` - нет, не говорите.

Comment: @metalurgus ну всмысле не правильно выразился)) В котором было скачено и запущено)

Comment: ок, понятно, теперь конкретно, что именно не получается? Выполнить код при первом запуске, или определить местоположение?

Comment: @metalurgus Да вообще не знаю с чего начать и чем воспользоваться для этого(

Comment: 1. Вы хотите хостить у себя, и при скачивании фиксировать город? Тогда это один вопрос. 2 вы хотите что б на гугле-store фиксировалось какие города качают - вопрос к гуглу. 3. Вы хотите при первом запуске определять и фиксировать город - тогда вам ответили первой ссылкой.

Comment: Решите отдельно вопрос "как выполнить код при первом запуске", и "как определить город". Совместите решение.

Comment: @nick_n_a Да вопрос в именно в том, что мне нужно фиксировать город и страну в котором зарегистрировался юзер. Я так понял, что первая ссылка то что мне нужно